# How to Initialize Variable based on placeholder in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a loop running through some data (which I cannot change/access) and I need to "initialize" a variable based on the placeholder data the first time the loop is running. Here's some equivalent dummy code:

```
    #This is the code I can modify
x =  K.placeholder()
v = K.variable( 0 )
y = v + x**2 #Want different behaviours for y after the first iteration

    #The code bellow can only run the session, I cannot change the structure from a for loop.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for value in [4,7,2,2,5,7,8,3,1]:
    print(sess.run( K.update(v,y) , feed_dict={x: value }) )
```

The problem is that I want y to change behaviour after the first update in the for loop, so I want *v* to "initialize" based on the first datapoint (in this case 0 + 4^2), and then do something different with the other datapoints. The reason for doing this is to speed up a process, basically I will be using the first datapoint to make a heavy calculation to get an initial value for*v* and then update the value using the following datapoints which is less expensive. Using tf.cond() is useless since it evaluates both return values and thus I might as well only run the heavy calculation for each datapoint.

I have tried to initialize the *v* variable based on the placeholder, but that does not appear to work. If anyone is familiar with Keras this is a part of an optimizer and it's get_updates() function, thus why I am not able to change the for loop running the updates.

This feels like a rather standard problem, how is it usually done with tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone experience similar problems, tf.cond does work to solve this I just accidentally used tensors I had defined outside of my fn_true and fn_false. Also it appears that for loops inside fn_true or fn_false breaks them and forces tensorflow to evaluate all branches.